# Android: Can WebView refresh only the js file

Tags: android, webview

I have an Activity which contains a WebView. Every time when starting this Activity, it'll load data from server, and write the data which is exactly a json object into a data.js file. Then webview will load a html file in a local folder, which will include that data.js file in a tag. In this Activity, users can refresh his data from server(do in java) and in turn refresh the data.js file. I just wonder is it possible for webview to only reload the data.js file, but keep the html and css file in its memory?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in your client side by using [$.getScript()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)

```
jQuery.loadScript = function (url, callback) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'script',
        success: callback,
        async: true
    });
}
```

By running this code you just load the script file wanted.

Comment: But I also need to save the data in Android database, it will be more convenient to do the loading job in java.